# Deserializing nested JSON string using GSON

Tags: java, json, api, gson, jira-rest-api

All,
I have the following `JSON` output/string (its a response from JIRA API):

```
{
    "expand": "names,schema",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 1,
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
            "id": "18200",
            "self": "https://localhost/rest/api/2/issue/18200",
            "key": "LS-1111",
        "fields": {
                "issuetype": {
                    "self": "https://localhost/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
                    "id": "3",
                    "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
                    "iconUrl": "https://localhost/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10318&avatarType=issuetype",
                    "name": "Task",
                    "subtask": false,
                    "avatarId": 10318
                },
                "timespent": 21600,
                "aggregatetimespent": 25200,
                "resolution": null,
                "customfield_11201": null,
                "project": {
                    "self": "https://localhost/rest/api/2/project/10100",
                    "id": "10100",
                    "key": "PROJKEY",
                    "name": "ProjectABCD",
                    "avatarUrls": {
                        "48x48": "https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?pid=10100&avatarId=10600",
                        "24x24": "https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10100&avatarId=10600",
                        "16x16": "https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10100&avatarId=10600",
                        "32x32": "https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10100&avatarId=10600"
                    }
                },
                "issuelinks": [
                    {
                        "id": "16202",
                        "self": "https://localhost/rest/api/2/issueLink/16202",
                        "type": {
                            "id": "10003",
                            "name": "Relates",
                            "inward": "relates to",
                            "outward": "relates to",
                            "self": "https://localhost/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10003"
                        }
                    }
                ]
        }
     }
    ]
}
```

I am using `GSON` for traversing through the elements and getting the values. I have written `POJO` classes following the "Nested Objects" example at

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

I am able to get the element values till 2nd level. Eg:
I am able to get the value of `response.expand`, `response.issues.get(0).expand` and other values till this level.
How can I get the value of `response.issues.get(0).fields.issuetype.id`?

How should I construct my deserializer and `POJO` class. Please assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

**AvatarUrls.java**

```
public class AvatarUrls {
    private String _48x48;
    private String _24x24;
    private String _16x16;
    private String _32x32;
    public String get_48x48() {
        return _48x48;
    }
    public void set_48x48(String _48x48) {
        this._48x48 = _48x48;
    }
    public String get_24x24() {
        return _24x24;
    }
    public void set_24x24(String _24x24) {
        this._24x24 = _24x24;
    }
    public String get_16x16() {
        return _16x16;
    }
    public void set_16x16(String _16x16) {
        this._16x16 = _16x16;
    }
    public String get_32x32() {
        return _32x32;
    }
    public void set_32x32(String _32x32) {
        this._32x32 = _32x32;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AvatarUrls [_48x48=" + _48x48 + ", _24x24=" + _24x24
                + ", _16x16=" + _16x16 + ", _32x32=" + _32x32 + "]";
    }
}
```

**Example.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    private String expand;
    private Integer startAt;
    private Integer maxResults;
    private Integer total;
    private List<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<Issue>();
    public String getExpand() {
        return expand;
    }
    public void setExpand(String expand) {
        this.expand = expand;
    }
    public Integer getStartAt() {
        return startAt;
    }
    public void setStartAt(Integer startAt) {
        this.startAt = startAt;
    }
    public Integer getMaxResults() {
        return maxResults;
    }
    public void setMaxResults(Integer maxResults) {
        this.maxResults = maxResults;
    }
    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public List<Issue> getIssues() {
        return issues;
    }
    public void setIssues(List<Issue> issues) {
        this.issues = issues;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [expand=" + expand + ", startAt=" + startAt
                + ", maxResults=" + maxResults + ", total=" + total
                + ", issues=" + issues + "]";
    }
}
```

**Fields.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Fields {
    private Issuetype issuetype;
    private Integer timespent;
    private Integer aggregatetimespent;
    private Object resolution;
    private Object customfield11201;
    private Project project;
    private List<Issuelink> issuelinks = new ArrayList<Issuelink>();
    public Issuetype getIssuetype() {
        return issuetype;
    }
    public void setIssuetype(Issuetype issuetype) {
        this.issuetype = issuetype;
    }
    public Integer getTimespent() {
        return timespent;
    }
    public void setTimespent(Integer timespent) {
        this.timespent = timespent;
    }
    public Integer getAggregatetimespent() {
        return aggregatetimespent;
    }
    public void setAggregatetimespent(Integer aggregatetimespent) {
        this.aggregatetimespent = aggregatetimespent;
    }
    public Object getResolution() {
        return resolution;
    }
    public void setResolution(Object resolution) {
        this.resolution = resolution;
    }
    public Object getCustomfield11201() {
        return customfield11201;
    }
    public void setCustomfield11201(Object customfield11201) {
        this.customfield11201 = customfield11201;
    }
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }
    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
    public List<Issuelink> getIssuelinks() {
        return issuelinks;
    }
    public void setIssuelinks(List<Issuelink> issuelinks) {
        this.issuelinks = issuelinks;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fields [issuetype=" + issuetype + ", timespent=" + timespent
                + ", aggregatetimespent=" + aggregatetimespent
                + ", resolution=" + resolution + ", customfield11201="
                + customfield11201 + ", project=" + project + ", issuelinks="
                + issuelinks + "]";
    }
}
```

**Issue.java**

```
public class Issue {
    private String expand;
    private String id;
    private String self;
    private String key;
    private Fields fields;
    public String getExpand() {
        return expand;
    }
    public void setExpand(String expand) {
        this.expand = expand;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    public void setSelf(String self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public Fields getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
    public void setFields(Fields fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Issue [expand=" + expand + ", id=" + id + ", self=" + self
                + ", key=" + key + ", fields=" + fields + "]";
    }
}
```

**Issuelink.java**

```
public class Issuelink {
    private String id;
    private String self;
    private Type type;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    public void setSelf(String self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Issuelink [id=" + id + ", self=" + self + ", type=" + type
                + "]";
    }
}
```

**Issuetype.java**

```
public class Issuetype {
    private String self;
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String iconUrl;
    private String name;
    private Boolean subtask;
    private Integer avatarId;
    public String getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    public void setSelf(String self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getIconUrl() {
        return iconUrl;
    }
    public void setIconUrl(String iconUrl) {
        this.iconUrl = iconUrl;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Boolean getSubtask() {
        return subtask;
    }
    public void setSubtask(Boolean subtask) {
        this.subtask = subtask;
    }
    public Integer getAvatarId() {
        return avatarId;
    }
    public void setAvatarId(Integer avatarId) {
        this.avatarId = avatarId;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Issuetype [self=" + self + ", id=" + id + ", description="
                + description + ", iconUrl=" + iconUrl + ", name=" + name
                + ", subtask=" + subtask + ", avatarId=" + avatarId + "]";
    }
}
```

**Project.java**

```
public class Project {
    private String self;
    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private AvatarUrls avatarUrls;
    public String getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    public void setSelf(String self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public AvatarUrls getAvatarUrls() {
        return avatarUrls;
    }
    public void setAvatarUrls(AvatarUrls avatarUrls) {
        this.avatarUrls = avatarUrls;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project [self=" + self + ", id=" + id + ", key=" + key
                + ", name=" + name + ", avatarUrls=" + avatarUrls + "]";
    }
}
```

**Type.java**

```
public class Type {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String inward;
    private String outward;
    private String self;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getInward() {
        return inward;
    }
    public void setInward(String inward) {
        this.inward = inward;
    }
    public String getOutward() {
        return outward;
    }
    public void setOutward(String outward) {
        this.outward = outward;
    }
    public String getSelf() {
        return self;
    }
    public void setSelf(String self) {
        this.self = self;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Type [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", inward=" + inward
                + ", outward=" + outward + ", self=" + self + "]";
    }
}
```

Now you can test it as -

**Main.java**

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
    import com.testgson.beans.Example;

    public class Main {
        private static Gson gson;

        static {
            gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        }

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             String j = "{\"expand\":\"names,schema\",\"startAt\":0,\"maxResults\":50,\"total\":1,\"issues\":[{\"expand\":\"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields\",\"id\":\"18200\",\"self\":\"https://localhost/rest/api/2/issue/18200\",\"key\":\"LS-1111\",\"fields\":{\"issuetype\":{\"self\":\"https://localhost/rest/api/2/issuetype/3\",\"id\":\"3\",\"description\":\"A task that needs to be done.\",\"iconUrl\":\"https://localhost/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10318&avatarType=issuetype\",\"name\":\"Task\",\"subtask\":false,\"avatarId\":10318},\"timespent\":21600,\"aggregatetimespent\":25200,\"resolution\":null,\"customfield_11201\":null,\"project\":{\"self\":\"https://localhost/rest/api/2/project/10100\",\"id\":\"10100\",\"key\":\"PROJKEY\",\"name\":\"ProjectABCD\",\"avatarUrls\":{\"48x48\":\"https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?pid=10100&avatarId=10600\",\"24x24\":\"https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10100&avatarId=10600\",\"16x16\":\"https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10100&avatarId=10600\",\"32x32\":\"https://localhost/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10100&avatarId=10600\"}},\"issuelinks\":[{\"id\":\"16202\",\"self\":\"https://localhost/rest/api/2/issueLink/16202\",\"type\":{\"id\":\"10003\",\"name\":\"Relates\",\"inward\":\"relates to\",\"outward\":\"relates to\",\"self\":\"https://localhost/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10003\"}}]}}]}";
             Example r = gson.fromJson(j, Example.class);
             System.out.println(r);

// This is how traversal can be done
        List<Issue> issues = r.getIssues();
        for(Issue i: issues) {
            System.out.println("Expand - " + i.getExpand());
            System.out.println("Id - " + i.getId());
            System.out.println("Self - " + i.getSelf());
            System.out.println("Key - " + i.getKey());
            System.out.println("Fields - " + i.getFields());
        }
        }
    }
```

**Result is -**

```
Example [expand=names,schema, startAt=0, maxResults=50, total=1, issues=[Issue [expand=operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields, id=18200, self=https://localhost/rest/api/2/issue/18200, key=LS-1111, fields=Fields [issuetype=Issuetype [self=https://localhost/rest/api/2/issuetype/3, id=3, description=A task that needs to be done., iconUrl=https://localhost/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10318&avatarType=issuetype, name=Task, subtask=false, avatarId=10318], timespent=21600, aggregatetimespent=25200, resolution=null, customfield11201=null, project=Project [self=https://localhost/rest/api/2/project/10100, id=10100, key=PROJKEY, name=ProjectABCD, avatarUrls=AvatarUrls [_48x48=null, _24x24=null, _16x16=null, _32x32=null]], issuelinks=[Issuelink [id=16202, self=https://localhost/rest/api/2/issueLink/16202, type=Type [id=10003, name=Relates, inward=relates to, outward=relates to, self=https://localhost/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10003]]]]]]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a specific way I can get part of the response. For eg: If I need to get "example.issues.key", how can I get that?

Comment: If you find this answer helpful then please accept the answer. Since, everything is in java object now, you can get the values.

Comment: Sure, I am accepting it as the answer. Could you please assist with a sample? How can I get the value of issues.key from Main class?