# How to get Json data

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json array like this

```
{
   "success":"true",
   "crops": {
           "Brinjal":[---varieties of brinjal---],
           "apple":[---varieties of apple---],
              .................
              .................
        }
}
```

So i have got the complete crops using.....

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
jsonObject.getString("crops")
```

but i actually need to create two arrays like

```
String[] crops = {"Brinjal","apple"};
String[] varities = {"---Brinjal Varities---","---apple varities---"};
```

how can I generate these two arrays
if i generate "crops" then i can generate other array....
so how can i generate the "crops"...

Comment: Are crops data is static which is coming in your json which brinjal, apple whatever it is??

Comment: This solution might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433340/java-parser-json-as-array-multidimensional :)

Answer (score 4):

You should do:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStringResp);
JSONObject cropsObj = obj.getJSONObject("crops");
JSONArray  arr1 = subObject.getJSONArray("Brinjal");
```

Then you iterate over the JSON array and create the String array.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void  main(String[]args){
    String joson = "{\n" +
     "   \"success\":\"true\",\n" +
     "   \"crops\": {\n" +
     "           \"Brinjal\":[---varieties of brinjal---],\n" +
     "           \"apple\":[---varieties of apple---],\n" +
     "              .................\n" +
     "              .................\n" +
     "        }\n" +
     "}";
    List<Object> apple = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> Brinjal = new ArrayList<Object>();
    apple.add("---varieties of apple---");
    Brinjal.add("---varieties of brinjal---");
    Map<String,Object> mapF = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    Map<String,Object> mapS = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    mapS.put("Brinjal", Brinjal);
    mapS.put("apple", apple);
    mapF.put("success", "true");
    mapF.put("crops",mapS );

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject().fromObject(mapF);
System.out.println(obj);

JSONObject objF = obj.getJSONObject("crops");
String[] ListF = {};
String str = objF.keySet().toString();
String strF = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
ListF = strF.split(", ");
List<Object> lsitF = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(int i = 0;i<ListF.length;i++){
    lsitF.add(objF.get(ListF[i]));[enter image description here][1]
}
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(lsitF.toString());

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. When posting an answer, try to be more informative: explain the error you have found and the solution you have posted: see also how to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String joson = "{\n" +
            "   \"success\":\"true\",\n" +
            "   \"crops\": {\n" +
            "           \"Brinjal\":[---varieties of brinjal---],\n" +
            "           \"apple\":[---varieties of apple---],\n" +
            "              .................\n" +
            "              .................\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "}";
    List<String> whereCrops = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> whereVarities = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] crops;
    String[] varities;
    ArrayList<String> contentKey = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(joson);

        JSONObject jsonCrops = myObject.getJSONObject("crops");
        Iterator<String> iter = jsonCrops.keys();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            whereCrops.add(key);

            Log.e("inningskey", key);
            try {


                JSONArray array = jsonCrops.getJSONArray(key);
                whereVarities.add(array.toString());


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Something went wrong!
            }
        }
         // here ! you need convert whereCrops to crops
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: very complicated to me it seems