# Parse Json file in java

Tags: java, json

For this json file

```
{
    "Name": "crunchify.com",
    "Author": "App Shah",
    "Company List": [
        "Compnay: eBay",
        "Compnay: Paypal",
        "Compnay: Google"
    ]
}
```

i used those code

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                        "G:/Contextual Search/balll.json"));

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
                String author = (String) jsonObject.get("Author");
                JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Company List");

                System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                System.out.println("Author: " + author);
                System.out.println("\nCompany List:");
                Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
```

How can I parse and get value of this critical JSON file? where there are nested into nested data. under body tag there is person and under person there are preferences and under preferences there are many value. Its too complicated to me to get the values. How can I get those values Please any suggestions?

```
{"body": 
{"group": "Family",
 "season": "Summer",
 "person": 
 {"gender": "Male", 
 "age": 23.0, 
 "id": 12258, 
 "preferences": [
 {"rating": 3, 
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00674898-160", 
 "tags": ["Romantic", "Seafood", "Family Friendly"]},
 {"rating": 2,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00247656-160",
 "tags": ["Bar-hopping"]},
 {"rating": 3,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00085961-160",
 "tags": ["Gourmet Food"]},
 {"rating": 4,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00086637-160",
 "tags": ["Family Friendly", "Local Food", "Entertainment"]},
 {"rating": 4,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00086308-160",
 "tags": ["Family Friendly", "Tourism"]},
 {"rating": 4, 
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00086622-160",
 "tags": ["Healthy Food",
 "Romantic", "Gourmet Food"]},
 {"rating": 2,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00809111-160",
 "tags": ["Wellness",
 "Family Friendly",
 "Sport"]},
 {"rating": 4,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00086310-160",
 "tags": ["Family Friendly", "Sport"]},
 {"rating": 4,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00340169-160",
 "tags": ["Fashion Bargains",
 "Live Music",
 "Shopping for accessories",
 "Family Friendly"]},
 {"rating": 4,
 "documentId": "TRECCS-00018110-160",
 "tags": ["Healthy Food", "Family Friendly", "Local Food", "Organic Food"]},
 {"rating": 2, "documentId": "TRECCS-00085880-160",
 "tags": ["Romantic", "Sailing", "Seafood"]},
 {"rating": 4, "documentId": "TRECCS-00259825-152", "tags": ["Family Friendly", "Budget Friendly"]}]},
 "trip_type": "Holiday", "duration": "Weekend trip", 
 "location": {"lat": 26.56285, "state": "FL", "id": 210, "lng": -81.94953000000001, "name": "Cape Coral"}},
 "candidates": ["TRECCS-00001063-210", "TRECCS-00001069-210", "TRECCS-00001080-210", "TRECCS-00001085-210",
 "TRECCS-00001086-210", "TRECCS-00001092-210", "TRECCS-00001102-210", "TRECCS-00001114-210", "TRECCS-00001148-210", 
 "TRECCS-00056424-210", "TRECCS-00056508-210", "TRECCS-00056589-210", "TRECCS-00056591-210", "TRECCS-00056687-210", 
 "TRECCS-00056715-210", "TRECCS-00316172-210", "TRECCS-00317050-210", "TRECCS-00552677-210", "TRECCS-00552744-210", 
 "TRECCS-00552876-210", "TRECCS-00553080-210", "TRECCS-00553240-210", "TRECCS-00553540-210", "TRECCS-00852498-210",
 "TRECCS-01452784-210"], "id": 2}
```

Comment: You can utilize jakson library for automactic deserializing json visit http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization link

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007600/deserializing-nested-json-string-using-gson for deserializing JSON using GSON library (includes nested JSON)

Comment: It is always a best option to use any library like GSON & JACKSON to parse json in to object and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

One option is always to iterate through the JSON fields as you showed in your question. Another, better, option is to deserialize the JSON into an object. Many JSON libraries support this feature. For example, with [Google's Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), your code would look like ...

```
class Group {
    String group;
    String season;
    MyPerson person;
}

class Person {
    String gender;
    double age;
    int id;
    MyPreference[] preferences;
}

class Preference {
    int rating;
    String documentId;
    String[] tags;
}
```

Then to deserialize the JSON ...

```
String json = "Your JSON ...";
Group group = new Gson().fromJson(json, Group.class);
```

Comment: There are many files how can i use them and waht fiels I need to solve this problem

Comment: If the files all have the same structure as the one above then you can simply read all the files into Strings and use the `fromJson` method with the same `Group` class. If the files have a different JSON structure it becomes a bit more complicated. You may need to declare classes for each type of JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

this is working Code with your JSON

```
 try {
  String responseString = "{\n"
  + "    \"Name\": \"crunchify.com\",\n"
  + "    \"Author\": \"App Shah\",\n"
  + "    \"Company List\": [\n"
  + "        \"Compnay: eBay\",\n"
  + "        \"Compnay: Paypal\",\n"
  + "        \"Compnay: Google\"\n"
  + "    ]\n"
  + "}";
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  Object obj = parser.parse(new String(responseString));
  JSONObject Object_index0 = (JSONObject) obj;
  String obj21 = Object_index0.get("Name").toString();
  String obj22 = Object_index0.get("Author").toString();
  Object obj23 = Object_index0.get("Company List");
  System.out.println("Name=>" + obj21 + "\nAuthor=>" + obj22 + "\nCompany List=> " + obj23);
  JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) Object_index0.get("Company List");
   for (int i = 0; i < lang.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("Company Name=>" + lang.get(i));
    }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and add org.json.simple jar . for any more clearification please ask 
happy to help . thanks